# Can very tight glasses restrict blood flow to the brain?

Tags: blood-circulation, glasses

Can extended use of glasses that are very tight-pressing against the temples inhibit blood circulation towards the brain?

I find that I get headaches if I wear tight glasses, and found a similar question here: [Can tight glasses cause headaches?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/can-tight-glasses-cause-headaches)
but it still doesn't clear out my doubts about blood flow.

Comment: I heavily edited to remove individual advice components, because it's a good basic-level question about the path of blood flow.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I just cast the final vote to approve your edit. With another 102 rep you won't need anyone to approve them. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not towards the brain.

Look at the two diagrams.  The temporal artery is a branch of the external carotid artery that stays outside the skull.  The internal carotid artery goes inside the skull.

[image]

You couldn't compress the skull with sunglasses if you tried.

[image]

[MANY headaches are related to muscular/tendinous pain in the head and neck](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1142908-overview), not the brain. Putting pressure on the temporal regions can cause pain in the muscles, and sustained pressure can cause spasms.  Restricting the flow through the arteries of your face could in theory reduce flow to muscles of your scalp, causing pain and ischemia.  It is less likely to be the cause of pain from sunglasses pressure, as there is lots of collateral blood flow, but not impossible.

Note that transmitting any force through the actual skull via compression, which is a pretty solid bone, would take a great deal of pressure (orders of magnitude above what sunglasses are capable of) and would involve fracturing bone. Then you'd be looking at potential stroke/TBI symptoms.  That is not happening to you.

I am not going to discuss your symptoms of confusion, that starts down the path of individual medical advice.  If you are concerned about any of your symptoms, see a doctor.

Get some better sunglasses or fix the hinges.

Comment: +1 You beat me by a few seconds, I had the same text typed and was just looking for a picture as reference. You could even point out that compressing the skull would also have notable effects and basically be a stroke.